# Can I borrow parts of an apache-licensed project for something not open-source?

Tags: licensing, android, apache-license

If I want to make a card game app or android, could I legally borrow parts of the Apache-2.0-licensed [Solitaire-for-Android](https://code.google.com/p/solitaire-for-android/)? Would I be able to charge such a project? (I was unable to understand the legal jargon in the license [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).)

Comment: yes you can. but you cant do back to them nor can anyone drag them to court if something you sold does not work or has other issues

Comment: Are you asking if you can change something and sell copies?  You can do that for any open source (as defined by the OSI) license, although it works better as a revenue stream with the least restrictive licenses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a very simple license, worth reading with due respect. If you can ask the question in English, I'm very sure you can comprehend the license - just try once again, without distractions.

In short, you can (section 3) IF you follow the rules (section 4 through 9). If you don't follow, then you are in violation.

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer and in your shoes, I'd get a legal opinion instead of a random dude online.